# Previous data is lost because of new data

Tags: javascript, html, json, class, object

I am creating some html tag and assigning data as below.

```
MyCombo = function(args) {
    var dataUrl = args.url;
    var divID = args.divID;
    var div = document.getElementById(divID);

    var myTable = '<input type="text" id="myInput"  list="myUL" onclick = "MyList()" onkeyup="MyList()" style="width:100% " >' +
        '<ul id="myUL" hidden=false>' + '<li>' + '<a href="#" ></a>' + '</li>' + '</ul>';
    div.innerHTML = myTable; 

    function getData(callback) {
        var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpRequest.open('GET', dataUrl, true);
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && httpRequest.status === 200) {
                callback(httpRequest.responseText);
            }
        };
        httpRequest.send();
    }

    getData(function(data) {
        var jsonc = JSON.parse(data);
        var new_opt = "";
        for (i = 0; i < jsonc.length; i++) {
            new_opt += '<li><a href="#">' + jsonc[i]['VALUE'] + '</a></li>';
        }
        document.getElementById('myUL').innerHTML = new_opt;
    });
}
```

Now when I pass my second div, previous data is getting lost. And for first div I am getting second data.

This how I am calling the class :

For the first instance

```
var myCombo = new liveSearch({
    "url": "data1.json",
    "divID": "ID1",
});
```

For the second instance

```
var myCombo2 = new liveSearch({
    "url": "data2.json",
    "divID": "ID2",
});
```

Any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: In HTML it is the same inside script tag I am fetching this.

Answer (score 0):

In getData you call

```
        document.getElementById('myUL').innerHTML = new_opt;
```

which writes to the element called `myUL` everytime it is called.

Comment: Do I need to remove that.

Comment: Or you can create the ul tag with an dynamic id something like everytime MyCombo is instanced.
in the ul tag put, id=myUL_ + newId , then in the end of callback call document.getElementById('myUL_'+ newId).innerHTML = new_opt;
and dont forget increment the newId ! newId ++

Comment: Are you willing to use jquery?

Comment: So, instead using css matching ID's use it with class

Answer (score 0):

Append instead of replacing

```
document.getElementById('myUL').appendChild(new_opt);
```

or you can append to the old

```
old_html = document.getElementById('myUL').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('myUL').innerHTML = old_html+new_opt;
```